# Segmentation fault using strcmp (Ubuntu)

Tags: c, ubuntu, token, strtok

I have the following code segment:

```
token = strtok(line, separator);
i = 0;
args[i++] = token;  /* build command array */
while( token != NULL ) /* walk through other tokens */
{
    /* printf( " %s\n", token ); */
    token = strtok(NULL, separator);
    if (strcmp(token, "|") != 0) {
        printf("entered");
    }
    else {
        args[i++] = token;
    }   /* and build command array */
```

The code compiles fine, but upon execution passing any argument, I receive the error "Segmentation fault (Core dumped)". Removing the if statement comparing the 2 strings solves the issue, so it is a problem with that comparison.

Comment: A token is a string (in this context). Are you asking how to check if two strings are equal?

Comment: Essentially, but I tried doing the simple if(token == "|"), but for some reason it wouldn't work...

Comment: C has no string comparison operation. Use `strcmp`.

Comment: Thank you! Like I said, I'm pretty new to C

Comment: Actually, now theres a new error, but i'll ask a different question for that

Comment: Didn't realize I can only post once every 90 minutes. Modified current question

Comment: `if (strcmp(token, "|") != 0) {` What does your debugger tell you the value of `token` is at the point of the crash?

Answer (score 1):

When `strtok` does not find next token it returns `NULL`, thus the segfault when trying to `strcmp(NULL, "|")`

Test if `token` is null before `strcmp`.

Answer (score 0):

the posted code:

```
token = strtok(line, separator);
i=0;
args[i++]=token;  /* build command array */
while( token != NULL ) /* walk through other tokens */
{
  /* printf( " %s\n", token ); */
  token = strtok(NULL, separator);
  if (strcmp(token, "|") != 0) {
      printf("entered");
  }
  else {
      args[i++] = token;
  }   /* and build command array */
```

contains a logic error.  the returned value from `strtok()` is being used before being checked.

suggest something similar to:

```
i=0;
token = strtok(line, separator);

while( token != NULL ) /* walk through other tokens */
{
    /* printf( " %s\n", token ); */
    if (strcmp(token, "|") != 0)
    {
        printf("entered");
    }

    else
    {
        args[i++] = token;
    }   /* and build command array */

    ...
    token = strtok(NULL, separator);
} // end while
```